# Different definition of antipode for $SL_q(2)$?

Tags: quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

In Majid's book (A Quantum Groups Primer) (pg11), the antipode for the Hopf algebra $SL_q(2)$ is defined as $Sd=a$, $Sa=d$, $Sb=-qb$,  $Sc=-q^{-1}c$.

However, in Kassel's book (Quantum Groups) (pg 84), there is an additional factor of $\det_q^{-1}$, i.e.
$S(a)=\det_q^{-1} d$,

$S(b)=\det_q^{-1} (-qb)$,

$S(c)=\det_q^{-1} (-q^{-1}c)$,

$S(d)=\det_q^{-1} a$

($\det_q^{-1}=ad-q^{-1}bc$)

May I ask, how do we reconcile these two different presentations of the antipode?

Sincere thanks for any help!

Comment: I have not had a closer look at their definitions, but do they define the comultiplications in the same way? Note that any bi-algebra has at most one antipode.

Comment: Thanks. In Kassel, it is written that the comultiplication $\Delta$ of $M_q(2)$ equip $SL_q(2)$ with Hopf algebra structures. And the comultiplications seem to be the same, $\Delta (a)=a\otimes a+b\otimes c$, etc. I am really puzzled.

Comment: That does not look like the comultiplication on any of the generators (in any of the ways I have seen it defined).

Comment: Actually, I guess I am confusing the relations with those of the quantum enveloping algebra.

Comment: Dear yoyostein: if you receive answers that are helpful, you can do two things: (1) you can upvote as many answers as you'd like; (2) you can accept one answer per question. To accept an answer, you simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. And you get 2 reputation points for each answer you accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antipode of Kassel's book is the antipode for $GL_q(2)$, while the one in Majid is for $SL_q(2)$. The latter is obtained from the former exactly by modding for $det_q-1$; this shows how to reconcile the two.